# View printers from Windows Print Server on a Mac

Tags: mac, windows

On windows,

> Get-Printer -ComputerName \\XXX

will give me a list of printers that exist on that print server. I wanted to accomplish the same\similar thing using a Mac.

The issue\reason:at my workplace, we have articles on how to add a windows network printer on a Mac. However, staffs without a windows machine won't know what the printer name is as we have hundreds of printers.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this on a command line but you should be able to access CUPS which is your Mac's printer subsystem remotely (assuming the firewall allows it.) by pointing a web browser to your Mac's IP address on port 631, EG HTTP://192.168.1.125:631. I suppose you might be able to write a script that would parse the output and return the info you need, but that might be more effort than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the steps to setup the shared printer on a  Windows 10 Pro (Version 1803) Machine.**

> Note: To get a better view of an image, either click on the image or open the image in a new window.

1. Open the "Control Panel".

   [image]
2. Next, select "Network and Sharing Center"

   [image]
3. Next, select "Change advanced sharing settings", then "Private
   (current Profile)". Make sure the you have the setting shown below.
   If necessary, click on the "Save changes" button.

   [image]
4. Next, select "All Networks". Make sure the you have the radio button
   "Turn off password protected sharing" selected. If necessary, click
   on the "Save changes" button.

   [image]
5. Next, return to the "Control Panel" and select "Devices and
       Printers". Right click on a desired printer to share and select
       "Printer properties".

   [image]
6. Click on the "Sharing" tab. Make sure the "Share this printer" box
   is checked off, then click on the "OK" button.

   [image]

**Here are the steps to select the shared printer on a Mac running High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6).**

1. Open the "Printer and Scanners" pane of the "System Preferences"
       application.

   [image]
2. Click on the "+" button. If neccessary, select "Add printer or
       scanner...". Next, click on the icon labeled "Windows"

   [image]
3. Select the computer ("herring" in this case), then select the
       "Guest" radio button and finally click on the "Connect" button.

   [image]
4. Select the printer and choose a driver, then click on the "Add"
       button.

   [image]
5. The added printer is shown below.

   [image]
6. When print to this shared printer, you may get the dialog box shown
   below. Enter the name "guest", then click on the "OK" button. You
   should not need a password.

   [image]

**A few final thoughts.**

- Both Windows and macOS were clean installs with all the default settings. Your workplace may have setup your computers with additional security that I did not have to deal with.
- Users of the Windows machine should check to make sure any shared folders require a password to allow access over the internet.
- I already had the driver for the example printer installed on the Mac. You may have not have this luxury.